# How to replace all same coming one by one chars in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few strings for example

```
-11 -11 --11
-22 ----22 -22
```

I need to replace any count of `-` coming one by one to single `-`.
After replacing i should get

```
-11 -11 -11
-22 -22 -22
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use replace on string with regex that matches more than one number of occurences of '-' with a single '-'

```
my_str = my_str.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-')
```

Comment: or a bit optimized for performance one - `my_str = my_str.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-')` which will not replace single `-` with `-`

Comment: @fanjabi Yes. Thats correct. Thanks for pointing it out.